# \markboth produces visible output in reledmac stanza

Tags: reledmac

My understanding of `\markboth` is that it sets tags for use in the header, but it does not immediately produce any output in the document. However, I'm finding that if you call `\markboth` within a reledmac stanza, it does produce visible output in the document.

Here's an example of the type of output I'm referring to:
[image]
As you can see, calling `\markboth` from within a reledmac stanza produces a blank line of output in the document.

The MWE to demonstrate this is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,asymmetric]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark--\leftmark}

\newcommand{\showverse}[2]{%
    \raisebox{0.5ex}{#2}\nobreak\hspace*{0.2em}%
}

\setstanzaindents{2,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{30pt}
\firstlinenum{100}

\begin{document}

\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{1}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{2}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{3}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

\beginnumbering
\stanza
This is a line of verse&
\markboth{1:4}{1:4}\showverse{1}{4}And another line of verse& % <=== \markboth produces visible output
And the last line of verse\&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Removing the `\markboth` command produces this output:
[image]

Does anyone know of a way I can call `\markboth` from within a reledmac stanza without producing this blank line output? Also, does anyone see something I'm doing wrong that is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `\doinsidethislinehook` as explained on § 5.7 of the handbook.

````
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,asymmetric]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark--\leftmark}

\newcommand{\showverse}[2]{%
    \raisebox{0.5ex}{#2}\nobreak\hspace*{0.2em}%
}

\setstanzaindents{2,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{30pt}
\firstlinenum{100}

\begin{document}

\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{1}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{2}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
\markboth{1:1}{1:1}\showverse{1}{3}Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

\beginnumbering
\stanza
This is a line of verse&
\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{1:4}{1:4}}\showverse{1}{4}And another line of verse& % <=== \markboth produces visible output
And the last line of verse\&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much!